# the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of $ x + y + z $
on the ellipsoid  ;
$$ \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2} {b^2}+ \frac {z^2} {c^2} =1 $$
where a, b and c are positive-valued constants.

so far I have found the 3 equation containing $ \lambda $ but after that when it comes to simplifying the equations to find the variables in terms of each other, I have no idea how to proceed.
my 3 equations containing $\lambda$ are: $$ \lambda = \frac {a^2}{2x} $$ $$ \lambda = \frac {b^2}{2y} $$ $$ \lambda = \frac {c^2}{2z} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your equations -

$x = \frac {a^2}{2\lambda}, y = \frac {b^2}{2\lambda}, z = \frac {c^2}{2\lambda}$...(i)

Substituting in $\, \frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2} {b^2}+ \frac {z^2} {c^2} =1$ ...(ii)

$\frac {a^2}{4\lambda^2} + \frac{b^2} {4\lambda^2}+ \frac {c^2} {4\lambda^2} =1$

$2\lambda = \pm \sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Given (ii), extreme values of $x + y + z = \pm\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}} = \pm \sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}$ (using equation (i)).